# Socket iOS swift client in objective-c projet : join room

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, socket.io

I am using [Socket IO swift client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) in objective c client , and I am not able to join a specific room cause to join a room I need to pass a the room Id:

```
 /**
 * join room
 *
 * @on   -> 'join'
 *
 * @access  -> user
 *
 * @param   ->
 *          |room      {messagingId}
 *
 * @emit  -> {status:, message}
 */
```

all I did find is :

```
  [socket on:@"join" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
    NSLog(@"join=>%@", data);
  }];
```

my question is how to pass messaginID as a param ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**First, A little description to make things clear**

/**
     Adds a Listener for an event.
     Returns: A unique id for the handler
     */

```
 public func on(event: String, callback: NormalCallback) -> NSUUID
```

---

/**
     Send a message to the server
     */

```
public func emit(event: String, _ items: AnyObject...)
```

**ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION**

the  on(event: String, callback: NormalCallback) -> NSUUID method you are using will only get you response from Server, to send Data use below code

So you need to use emit to join room

```
[socket emit: @"join", messaginID];
```

Answer (score 1):

**///////*********SocketIO********///////**

```
NSString     *User      = FORMAT(@"user_%@",[USERDEFAULT objectForKey:useridkey]);
NSDictionary *param     = @{@"id": User};

NSData  *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:param options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData: data
                                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:CHAT_URL];

socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url config:@{@"log": @NO, @"reconnectAttempts" : @50, @"reconnects" : @YES, @"forcePolling": @YES}];

//******* connect socket *******////
[socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray* data, SocketAckEmitter* ack) {
    NSLog(@"socket connected");
    [socket emit:@"join" with:@[jsonString]];
}];



////******* For receive events *******////
[socket on:@"message" callback:^(NSArray * _Nonnull arrayData, SocketAckEmitter * _Nonnull ack) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [arrayData description]);

    NSString *other_userid = FORMAT(@"%@",[[arrayData valueForKey:@"r_id"] objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSString *senderid = FORMAT(@"%@",[[arrayData valueForKey:@"s_id"] objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSString *classified_id = FORMAT(@"%@",[[arrayData valueForKey:@"classified_id"]objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSString *time = FORMAT(@"%@",[[arrayData valueForKey:@"time"]objectAtIndex:0]);
    NSDictionary *temp;

    if([classified_id isEqualToString:_classifiedid] && [other_userid isEqualToString:FORMAT(@"user_%@",selfuser.idstring)]) {

        NSString *message = FORMAT(@"%@",[[arrayData valueForKey:@"msg"]objectAtIndex:0]);

        temp = @{
                 @"msg":message,
                 @"time":time,
                 @"s_id":senderid,
                 @"r_id":other_userid
                 };

        [self addChatObjectToChatArray:temp];

    }

}];


[socket on:@"error" callback:^(NSArray * _Nonnull arrayData, SocketAckEmitter * _Nonnull ack) {
    NSLog(@"error with -- %@ && ACK -- %@", [arrayData description], [ack debugDescription]);
}];


[socket setReconnects:YES];
[socket connect];
```